# flask app only shows list of files with apache2

Tags: python, apache, flask

Im trying to host a flask app with an apache2 server. The server works but I'm only seeing a list of files, the wonderful "index of" page. My code is pretty simple. This is my hello.py file in /var/www/flask_dev:

```
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def hello_world():
return 'Hello World!'

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0')
```

I also created an apache config file located in /etc/apache2/sites-available/flask_dev.conf:

```
ServerName example.com

<VirtualHost *:80>

        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
        WSGIDaemonProcess hello user=www-data group=www-data threads=5     python-path=/var/www/flask_dev
        WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/flask_dev/start.wsgi
        <Directory /var/www/flask_dev>
                WSGIProcessGroup hello
                WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}
                Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
                AllowOverride None
                Require all granted
        </Directory>

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

And the needed wsgi file also located in /var/www/flask_dev/start.wsgi:

```
from hello import app as application

import sys
sys.stdout = sys.stderr
```

I'm not sure what I did wrong, I just followed a simple tutorial.

Thanks for your help :)

Comment: Have you copied or symlinked that conf file into sites-enabled?

Comment: For your `WSGIDaemonProcess` and `WSGIProcessGroup`, does the user and group "hello" actually exist? Try putting a real user that exists on the system there (and one that has permissions to your `/var/www/flask_dev`). Also have you looked into error.log when restarting the apache service?

Comment: The error.log shows it's unable to import name "app", but I only followed a tutorial and it seemed to work for them. And target WSGI script cannot be loaded as python module is also shown

Comment: @User3745172 I am having the same issue. How did you solve this?

Comment: A bit of trial and error, but in the end you have to make sure to enable the conf file created for flask in apache which I did not. Hope that helps

Answer (score 0):

You probably did not install `mod_wsgi` module for Apache.

http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/deploying/mod_wsgi/

Apache needs to import the `mod_wsgi` module for it to work with python. Further instructions for installation can be found at.

https://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/QuickInstallationGuide

Once installed, edit your `httpd.conf` with `LoadModule wsgi_module modules/mod_wsgi.so`

If you are on Windows, you will have to download the appropriate `mod_wsgi.so` for the python version and architecture. Rename the file to `mod_wsgi.so` if it has any python specific version naming and set conf to LoadModule.

Comment: Just run: a2enmod wsgi