# Deploying flask app with apache2 only shows index

Tags: python, flask, apache2

I'm trying to deploy a simple hello world flask app on a linux server (Ubuntu 18.04.3). I'm logged into the linux box as `bobtheuser`. However, when I access the ip address, I only see the contents "Index of/" listing the contents of `/var/www/html/`, i.e. the flask webapp isn't starting up.

**flask app setup**
The app directory is setup like so:

```
'/var/www/html/helloflask
├── __init__.py
├── my_flask_app.py
├── my_flask_app.wsgi
```

**my_flask_app.py**

```
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/")
def hello():
    return "Hello world! Hello Apache2 webserver!"

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

**my_flask_app.wsgi**

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import logging
import sys
logging.basicConfig(stream=sys.stderr)
sys.path.insert(0, '/var/www/html/helloflask/')
from my_flask_app import app as application
application.secret_key = 'helloflask-sk'
```

**/etc/apache2/sites-available/helloflask.conf**

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
     # Add machine's IP address (use ifconfig command)
     ServerName 128.250.89.117
     # Give an alias to to start your website url with
     WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/html/helloflask/my_flask_app.wsgi
     <Directory /var/www/html/helloflask>
     # set permissions as per apache2.conf file
            Options FollowSymLinks
            AllowOverride None
            Require all granted
     </Directory>
     ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
     LogLevel warn
     CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

A similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34966680/flask-app-only-shows-list-of-files-with-apache2), but I've already implemented the suggested solution, to no avail.

Comment: did you copy/link it in folder `sites-enabled` ?

Comment: `sites-enabled` is symlinked to `sites-available`. I checked, though, and `helloflask.conf` is indeed in `sites-enabled`.

Comment: if you have file or link in `sites-enabled` then it should use this config but if you have other config with `ServerName 128.250.89.117` then I don't know which one it will use - first or last.

Comment: you have configured `.log` files so you could check what you get in these files - maybe there will be error message.